# django: UserCreationForm: add_error to both passwords when pass validation fails

Tags: django

curretly in `UserCreationForm` (django.contrib.auth.forms)  Django has

```
    def _post_clean(self):
        super()._post_clean()
        # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
        # by super().
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password:
            try:
                password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
            except forms.ValidationError as error:
                self.add_error('password2', error)
```

But due to this when i fill same password but not a valid passwrod, it shows error on only password2 field and password1 it shows no error

[image]

i want both the password fields to be shown error, when password validation fails

how can i do this

i tried

```
    def _post_clean(self):
        super()._post_clean()
        # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
        # by super().
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password:
            try:
                password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
            except forms.ValidationError as error:
                self.add_error('password2', error)
                self.add_error('password1', error)
```

But this does not work